# Create all combinations of a single column from a file into two columns using awk or shell script or python

Tags: python, shell, awk

I have a file which contains airport code like below

```
ATQ 
HYD 
BLR
GOI 
AMD
CCJ
TRV
```

from the same file i have to create source destination mapping like below in gawk.

```
 src dest
 ATQ HYD
 ATQ BLR
 ATQ GOI
 ATQ AMD
 ATQ CCJ
 ATQ TRV
 HYD ATQ
 HYD BLR
 HYD AMD
 ....
 ...
```

can anyone help me here,thanks in advance

Comment: you missed your attempts

Comment: I don't understand how you intend to map source to destination. Is it simply a list of all possible combinations?

Comment: its just create route combinations for the existing airport code values

Comment: @Chethu: Provide your observations on the provided answers so that people will help you out further

Answer (score 1):

A simple `awk` script could do this. Just store all the elements of the line in array and run a loop for each element for every other element without repetitions which don't make sense.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf("%s\t%s\n" ,"src", "dest")}
  {
      line[++c] = $1
  }
  END {
      for ( i = 1; i <= c; i++ )
      {
          for ( j = 1; j <= c; j++ )
          {
              if (line[i] != line[j]) { printf("%s\t%s\n",line[i],line[j]) }
          }
       }
  }
' file
```

will output,

```
src     dest
ATQ     HYD
ATQ     BLR
ATQ     GOI
ATQ     AMD
ATQ     CCJ
ATQ     TRV
HYD     ATQ
HYD     BLR
HYD     GOI
HYD     AMD
HYD     CCJ
HYD     TRV
BLR     ATQ
BLR     HYD
BLR     GOI
BLR     AMD
BLR     CCJ
BLR     TRV
GOI     ATQ
GOI     HYD
GOI     BLR
GOI     AMD
GOI     CCJ
GOI     TRV
AMD     ATQ
AMD     HYD
AMD     BLR
AMD     GOI
AMD     CCJ
AMD     TRV
CCJ     ATQ
CCJ     HYD
CCJ     BLR
CCJ     GOI
CCJ     AMD
CCJ     TRV
TRV     ATQ
TRV     HYD
TRV     BLR
TRV     GOI
TRV     AMD
TRV     CCJ
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
 echo "src dest"; cat /tmp/air | while read s; do for d in `cat /tmp/air`; do if [ $s != $d ]; then echo $s $d; fi; done; done
```

Will output:

```
src dest
ATQ HYD
ATQ BLR
ATQ GOI
ATQ AMD
ATQ CCJ
ATQ TRV
HYD ATQ
HYD BLR
HYD GOI
HYD AMD
HYD CCJ
HYD TRV
BLR ATQ
BLR HYD
BLR GOI
BLR AMD
BLR CCJ
BLR TRV
GOI ATQ
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Version in bash assuming your airport list is in `a.txt` file:

```
echo "src dest";
for src in `cat a.txt`; do
    for dest in `cat a.txt`; do
        if [ $src != $dest ]; then
            echo "$src $dest";
        fi
    done;
done
```

Comment: This will also print 'ATQ ATQ'